# Перевод сообщений про новые очереди проверок

Tags: дефект, локализация, очередь-проверок

У нас тут [обновились очереди проверок](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release), и, насколько я понял, через них Дух может постить комментарии:

- ✓[Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16720)
- ✓[Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16706)
- ✓[Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16705)
- ✓[Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16715)
- ✓[Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16717)
- ✓[Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16702)

По-моему эти строки важно перевести максимально оперативно, а то народ уже начал потихоньку подумывать, что он на англоязычном сайте :)

Ну и другие новые строки, которые я нашёл:

- ✓[We’ve deprecated the Help & Improvement queue and replaced First posts with First questions and First answers. Read more about it on Meta.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16736)
- ✓[First questions](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16692)
- ✓[Help new users be successful on the site by reviewing their first questions.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16730)
- ✓[The purpose of this queue is to give special attention to posts submitted by new users whose questions are more likely to need improvement.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16716)
- ✓[First answers](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16690)
- ✓[Help new users be successful on the site by reviewing their first answers.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16725)
- ✓[The purpose of this queue is to give special attention to posts submitted by new users whose answers are more likely to need improvement.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16713)
- ✓[**Edit** or **share feedback** on answers that are good, but could use some help.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16703)
- ✓[Choose **Looks OK** if the post is fine as-is.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16724)
- ✓[Be sure to **upvote** good posts to encourage new users.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16695)
- ✓[Share feedback on this new user question](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16711)
- ✓[Share feedback on this new user answer](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16719)
- ✓[We will post your selected feedback anonymously. If you want to leave a comment under your own username, use the standard comment link.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16714)
- ✓[Question is unclear](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16722)
- ✓[Question is too broad](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16696)
- ✓[Question needs some code](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16709)
- ✓[Question has too much code](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16710)
- ✓[Answer is unclear](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16699)
- ✓[Answer needs supporting information](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16700)
- ✓[Share feedback](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16721) (текст кнопки, которая отправляет анонимный комментарий)
- ✓[This question can be understood and answered as-is (be sure to vote accordingly).](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16697)
- ✓[This question is good as-is and not low quality (be sure to vote accordingly).](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16708)
- ✓[This answer is good as-is and not low quality (be sure to vote accordingly).](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16707)
- ✓[Improve and correct problems with this question yourself.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16718)
- ✓[Improve and correct problems with this answer yourself.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16712)
- ✓[Leave a helpful comment for the new poster.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16704)

(возможно это не все, я новыми очередями ещё не пользовался — можно попробовать перебрать соседние id для поиска остального или посмотреть скриншоты на enSO)

Comment: видимо, из той же оперы: вообще [пустая плашка в очереди первых вопросов](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqEoh.png), на которой должен быть текст «Спасибо! Сегодня вы проверили 20 *таких-то* сообщений. Возвращайтесь через *столько-то*, чтобы продолжить проверку.». подозреваю, что и в очереди первых ответов будет аналогично. // [пример заполненной плашки](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umyhU.png)

Comment: Список последних добавленных строк можно посмотреть здесь: https://msdn-whiteknight.github.io/Traducir-Lab/html/recent.htm (сгенерировано из БД Traducir). Строки по очередям проверок были добавлены примерно с 04.07 по 27.07

Comment: Я поутверждал некоторые строки, которые счёл готовыми. Некоторые стоит подправить, пока не углублялся.

Comment: отдельного поста на мете не нашёл, но хотелось бы знать, статистика по закрытым очередям покинула чат?

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov статистика вроде осталась: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/stats Или вы о том, что статистика в счет знаков за закрытую очередь обнулилась, и знаки придется зарабатывать заново?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight да, именно про это. В новых очередях статистика как я понял с чистого нуля?

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov Да, с нуля. Есть предложение засчитывать в новых очередях статистику со старой очереди, пока непонятно, сделают или нет: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369016/370389

Comment: текст на плашках в очередях первых вопросов и первых ответов (см. мой первый комментарий) появился, но [на смеси языков](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHJs4.png): `Thank you for reviewing 20 first answers; come back через 9 часов to continue reviewing.`/`Thank you for reviewing 20 first questions; come back через 9 часов to continue reviewing.`

Answer (score 7):

Предложил:

- [**Проголосуйте за** хорошие сообщения, чтобы поощрить новых участников.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16695)
- [Выберите **Выглядит нормально**, если сообщение выглядит нормально в текущем виде.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16724)
- [Улучшить ответ и исправить его проблемы самостоятельно.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16712)
- [Улучшить вопрос и исправить его проблемы самостоятельно.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16718)
- [Оставить отзыв](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16721)
- [Оставить отзыв на этот ответ нового участника](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16719)
- [Оставить отзыв на этот вопрос нового участника](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16711)
- [Цель этой очереди — обратить особое внимание на сообщения от новых участников, ответы которых, скорее всего, нуждаются в улучшении.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16713)
- [Цель этой очереди — обратить особое внимание на сообщения от новых участников, вопросы которых, скорее всего, нуждаются в улучшении.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16716)
- [Обновление очередей проверок](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16737)

---

**Обновление:** предложил еще несколько строк:

- [При попытке отправить отзыв произошла ошибка. Попробуйте ещё раз.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16698)
- [Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16720)
- [В вопрос нужно добавить код.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16709)
- [Упразднена](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16648) (*надпись у старой очереди первых сообщений*)
- [Этот ответ хорош в текущем виде и не является низкокачественным (проголосуйте соответствующим образом).](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16707)
- [Этот вопрос в текущем виде можно понять и дать на него ответ (проголосуйте соответствующим образом).](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16697)
- [Этот вопрос хорош в текущем виде и не является низкокачественным (проголосуйте соответствующим образом).](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16708)
- [Мы опубликуем выбранный вами отзыв анонимно. Если вы хотите оставить комментарий от своего имени, используйте стандартную ссылку комментария.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16714)
- [Мы упразднили очередь «Помощь и Улучшение» и заменили «Первые сообщения» на «Первые вопросы» и «Первые ответы». Узнайте больше об этом на Мете.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16736)

Comment: Про «помощь и улучшение» у нас вообще не знают. Это enSO-specific. То есть строка не должна пролезать в интерфейс ruSO в идеале.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Она пролезла (строку видимо сделали общей для всех сайтов), но она отображалась только в уведомлении, когда первый раз заходишь в обновленные очереди проверок. Так что ее наличие не очень большая проблема.

Answer (score 5):

Добавил:

First questions -> [Первые вопросы](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16692)

Help new users be successful on the site by reviewing their first questions. -> [Помогите новым пользователям добиться успеха на сайте проверив их первые вопросы.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16730)

Leave a helpful comment for the new poster. -> [Оставьте полезный комментарий для нового пользователя.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16704)

Answer is unclear -> [Ответ непонятен](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16699)

Question has too much code -> [Вопрос содержит очень много кода](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16710)

First answers -> [Первые ответы](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16690)

Question is unclear -> [Вопрос непонятен](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16722)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem. -> [Пожалуйста добавьте достаточно кода, чтобы другие пользователи могли понять или воспроизвести проблему.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16705)

Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations. -> [Добавьте дополнительные сведения, чтобы расширить свой ответ, например рабочий код или ссылки на документацию.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16702)

Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution. -> [Пожалуйста, добавьте к своему ответу дополнительную информацию. В текущем виде, ваше решение сложно понять.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16717)

Question is too broad -> [Вопрос слишком общий](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16696)

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example. -> [Пожалуйста сократите ваш код, чтобы облегчить поиск вашей проблемы. Следуйте следуйте этим рекомендациям, чтобы создать [минимальный воспроизводимый пример]($url$).](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16715)

Comment: Не хватает запятой перед "проверив их первые вопросы", после "пожалуйста". "Пользователи" -> "Участники" (утвержденный термин). "Как сейчас написано" лучше заменить на "В текущем виде".

Comment: а редактировать получается нельзя? только удалить и создать заново перевод?

Comment: Да, или нажать replace (которая должна делать то же самое)

Comment: я не могу нажать replace, наверное прав не хватает

Comment: «minimal reproducible example» обычно переводят как «минимальный воспроизводимый пример»

Comment: я думал что это не переводится) сейчас поправлю