# Отсутствие переводов в комментариях от Духа сообщества

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, комментарии, дух-сообщества

[Пользователь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) комментирует на английском языке вопросы, которые заданы на русском, [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1321785/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-ip-%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83).

Это нормальное его поведение?

Comment: Дополнительно, см. [Совместный перевод сайта сообществом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1032/176217).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Комментарии от Духа сообщества это новая фишка, переводы ещё не были выполнены.

Добавил пару переводов:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16706
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14548

Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2021.8.26.40077

Уже опубликованные комментарии могут остаться на английском языке.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!

Comment: Ни разу до этого не видел комментариев от Духа. Что заставляет его вмешиваться? Как он определяет необходимость комментария?

Comment: @МаксимФисман, если я верно понял ситуацию: комментарии добавляются при использовании участниками новых очередей на проверку (участником выбирается решение по проверяемому посту из очереди - под постом автоматически добавляется коммент от имени Духа). См. [связанный вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11683/288409).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1322771/235436 Комментарий не переведён

Comment: @КириллМалышев. [Перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16720) на текущий момент уже выполнен. Если в новых сборках не будет подхватываться, надо отдельную багу заводить, может даже на MSE сразу.

Comment: @КириллМалышев [уже по-русски](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1322895/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception#comment2337439_1322895)