# Перевод сообщения при достижении лимита проверок в новых очередях

Tags: дефект, локализация, очередь-проверок

При достижении лимита проверок (*20шт в день*) в новых очередях проверок(новые вопросы и новые ответы) на странице https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review появляются следующие сообщения:

> Thank you for reviewing 20 first answers; come back через X часов to
> continue reviewing.

В очереди первых ответов.

И сообщение

> Thank you for reviewing 20 first questions; come back через X часов to
> continue reviewing.

В очереди первых вопросов.

**Выглядит это так:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

@aleksandrbarakin, неоднократно уже сообщал об этом в [комментариях](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11683/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba#comment50334_11683) и в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59114868#59114868).
Тем не менее непосредственно в постах на мете этого нет, поэтому я "*оставлю это здесь*", чтобы не потерялось и чтобы мы не забыли перевести эти сообщения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложил переводы:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16871
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16872
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16873
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16859
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16860
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16861

> @aleksandrbarakin, неоднократно уже сообщал об этом в комментариях и в чате.

Сообщать об отсутствии переводов в чате довольно сомнительная идея. Там эти сообщения мы можем не заметить, а если и заметим, то забудем о них. Как и бессмысленно *неоднократно* сообщать об одних и тех же строках. Если строки долго висят без перевода и это серьезно беспокоит, найдите строку в Traducir и поставьте отметку "This string needs a new translation ASAP". Это к тому же и уменьшит работу для того, кто будет делать переводы.

Comment: Спасибо большое! А что нужно сделать чтобы они в следующую сборку вошли? У αλεχολυτ(или кого еще?) есть права на то чтобы заапрувить конкретные варианты?

Comment: @МихаилРебров Да, αλεχολυτ должен утвердить. Он просматривает мету и должен увидеть этот ответ, так что ничего особенного делать не надо.

Comment: спасибо еще раз. Надеюсь αλεχολυτ отпишется в комментариях. Я придержу пока ответ как нерешенный, чтобы он не потерялся. Как Алекс отпишется или перевод появится - отмечу ответ. Плюсик я сразу поставил)

Comment: @МихаилРебров утвердил

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Спасибо тебе!)